# Run openssl commands in the runtime in the ios application device

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, openssl

I have to generate .crt.pem and .key.pem file from the .p12 file in the iOS Application feature.
It requires for security reasons only I need to run open ssl commands on ios app.
For Example:

`openssl pkcs12 -in user.p12 -out user.key.pem -nocerts -nodes`

`openssl pkcs12 -in user.p12 -out user.crt.pem -nocerts -nodes`

These commands easily I can run on the terminal on macOS but my requirement is to generate these dynamically within the application.

Please suggest any other solution is avaialble.

Comment: Try with [this](https://medium.com/@joncardasis/openssl-swift-everything-you-need-to-know-2a4f9f256462)

Comment: I found also [this package](https://swiftpackageindex.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL)